# Can't use numpy methods after uninstalling and reinstalling the numpy package

Tags: python, numpy, pip, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

I have recently upgraded tensorflow and it seemed to have install a numpy version that has conflicts with what I had installed so I received warnings while running codes involving numpy, so I decided to uninstall and reinstall numpy with simple `pip uninstall numpy` and `pip install numpy` commands in Windows 10 cmd. As I uninstalled the package for the first time, I got an access denied error, probably because the Jupyter Notebook was opened and tensorflow was being used at that time. After I closed the Jupyter Notebook, and tried to use numpy again, I couldn't get access to simple methods like `arange`. The error message is as following:

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'arange'
```

I tried to run `dir(numpy)`, and that's was I got:

```
['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

I reinstalled numpy multiple times as well upgraded it, but that didn't solve the problem. I have also been looking through similar questions in Stackoverflow, but I am not able to solve the problem. Anything I can do with it except completely reinstalling Anaconda and Python?

p.s. After reinstalling numpy (or upgrading tensorflow), I receive the following warning which I never saw before when using Python in cmd:

`Warning: This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment please see https://conda.io/activation`

I am not sure whether that's related to the issue at all, but just for your information I am trying to include all issues I have around the reinstallation.

Edit: I solved the problem in the most brute force way: reinstalling Anaconda. But to avoid something like this from happening again in the future, I'm still interested to know the source of the problem and its solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, virtual environments, can save you a lot of trouble with uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda. I believe the command is something like `python venv -m [name of virtual environment]` I would definitely verify that this is the correct command. I believe it creates the vitual environment in the current directory. I'm not entirely sure how to use one on Windows, but I use them extensively on Linux systems. Using a virtual  environment means not having to reinstall conda everytime some goes screwy with the package intallations as far as I know. When a problem comes up, you just nuke the virtual environment. Admittedly, this is still somewhat of pain because you have to reinstall all of the packages to the new virtual environment that you will be needing, but I find it much less of a pain than having to reinstall Anaconda.

Second, I would just install your choice of Tensorflow via the standard `pip install tensorflow==[version]` and then maybe updating numpy later. This is as opposed to updating to newest version of numpy before installing tensorflow. Also, uninstalling and re-installing tensorflow is also advised, once again, not from the cached package.

Another thing to note, is that if you uninstall and reinstall a package via pip, is that  preventing it from reinstalling from the cached package is sometimes necessary. I have run into similar situations that required where I have installed updates only to watch it "brick" my python environment. This all tends to be a dependency issue, but I think you knew that already.

FYI: I'm running tensorflow-gpu==2.4.1 and numpy==1.19.4

Regarding the activation error, I have only received that after fresh installations of Anaconda, so you having received it after only reinstalling numpy is very odd.